# Get all keys of Object in this when we use one of the key as self invoking function in Node.js /Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to call other keys from self invoking function by using this keyword.Currently i am doing it this way.

```
module.exports = function (url_obj) {

    return {

        const: (function () {
          //unable to get add function also when i use this keyword
           ##console.log(this);##
             this.value_main=33;//unable to change its value as i am not getting value_main key in "this"
        })(), 

        add : function () {}, 
        value_main:12
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem is to store the object on a var, and pass it as an argument to the self invoking function :

```
var myObj = { 
    add : function () {}, 
    value_main:12
};
myObj.const_val = (function(self){
                      self.value_main = 13
                    //self.otherkey...
                    //self.add();
                      console.log(self);
                      return;// return value if you want const_val to have one
                 })(myObj);
return myObj;
```

`const` is a keyword in javascript (ES6), so you can't use it as a key.
If you really want to do so, you can use `{"const": ...}`, but it's a bad idea.

Comment: Hey 
It really helped. Actually i am trying to have a constructor inside object so that when the current file load the constructor will automatically called and from that i can call other keys which are present inside object

Comment: You can call whatever key you want on the self invoking function (and set some if needed)